# Let $f,g \in C^1((a,b);\mathbb{R}). $ Show that if $\exists \ x \in (a,b) \ s.t. \ f(x)g'(x) \neq f'(x)g(x)$ then $f,g$ are l.i.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let $f,g \in C^1((a,b);\mathbb{R}). $ Show that if $\exists \ x \in (a,b) \ s.t. \ f(x)g'(x) \neq f'(x)g(x)$ then $f,g$ are l.i.

I don't have any idea how to prove this statement. Also I don't know if it has a name. In the book I'm following it is just an exercise. If anyone knows, please post in the comments.

Comment: Bom Dia Piero. Please include your problem in the content, not only in the title. Are you familiar with Reductio ad absurdum ?

Comment: @Hamdiken Hi, thanks for advising. Yes, I'm familiar, but still don't have any idea.

Comment: What does it mean when two functions are linearly independent ? Write the definition, take its negation, and apply reductio ad absurdum to get to a contradiction. Good so far ?

Comment: Contrapositive works fine: If $F(x)=cG(x)$ then $F(x)G'(x)=F(x)cF'(x)=cF(x)F'(x)=G(x)F'(x)$

Comment: @Hamdiken Ok, I got it.

Comment: @QC_QAOA I guess that you suppose $G(x)=cF(x)$, not the inverse (in your demo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By contrapositive: If $cF(x)=G(x)$ then

$$F(x)G'(x)=F(x)cF'(x)=cF(x)F'(x)=G(x)F'(x)$$